# Using a wildcard in nested YAML value

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, jq, wildcard, yq

I need to retrieve a value from a yaml which I'm currently using yq for, like this:

```
yq '.Resources.TestGlueJob.Properties.Name' cft/*.yaml
```

where TestGlueJob can have different values. So I'm trying to use a wildcard like this, but that is giving me null as return value:

```
yq '.Resources.*.Properties.Name' cft/*.yaml
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the object iterator `[]`?

```bash
yq '.Resources[].Properties.Name' cft/*.yaml
```

Comment: Yes, I eventually got it working like that